# Coded UI test issue with IE 11

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I have created Coded UI Test and i can run it successfully in IE 8,9,10 but when i run in IE 11 code browser just open and throws the following error :

> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Technology
>   NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll but was not handled in
>   user code"

System Spec:
Win 7 64-bit
IE 11 64-bit

Comment: If you provide a call stack and some relevant parts of your test code maybe someone can help you to find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If youre running 64bit version of IE11 and Windows lower than 8 there are some compatibility issues. Check with IE11 32bit version first and see if it helps.

From MSDN social:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/15d12b5c-f222-4607-aa20-de227befaad8/coded-ui-code-not-working-on-ie11